# Is there support for animation, transition effects in Angular Bootstrap?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

Is there any animation support in Angular Bootstrap?  I'm not seeing any built-in way to slide a collapse element in, out, up or down.  It just pops when activated.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for animation in the [ng-bootstrap Collapse](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples), however it looks like it's on the roadmap (source: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/295).

As it stands, you can add animations by using CSS - please see [this demo](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/LtWoySYTvpSe3gnm) for an example.

I've added the following CSS to the `collapse-basic` component in the demo which will fade in/out the element when the Toggle button is clicked:

```
.collapse, .collapse.show {
  display: block;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.collapse {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.collapse.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Your sample works, but when I add this to my code, no animation occurs.  I checked for any other styles on the collapse div but nothing seems to conflict.  Am I missing something other than adding the styles?

Comment: I took the demo directly from [ng-bootstraps website](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples) and just added the CSS file (making sure to include it in the `styleUrls` property of the Component decorator. What version of ng-bootstrap are you using? Maybe they have changed the classes recently and you might need to apply the styles to different classes. You could inspect your HTML and post a snippet of the element to see what the classes relating to "collapse" are called in your code